# date formatting issues. js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Date formatting issues after July.the date shown is a weekly format. any help will be highly appreciated.the date is working fine just that not working as expected

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var curr = new Date; // get current date
        var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
        var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6
        var startDate = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
        startDate = ((startDate.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0'
                : '')
                + (startDate.getMonth() + 1)
                + "/"
                + ((startDate.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + startDate
                        .getDate())
                + "/"
```

Comment: When you work with native Date object in JavaScript, you need to make some additional calculations.

They are not nessasary if you are using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library. It makes your development much more comfortable.
So, if you are going to work with date manipulation further in this or other projects, I recommend you to start using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)  right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change this code

```
 var endDate = new Date(startDate);
 endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 6);
```

You can check below working code.

```js
   

$(document).ready(function () {
        //var curr = new Date('2020-02-29'); // for leap
        var curr = new Date();// get current date
        var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
        var startDate = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
        var endDate = new Date(startDate);
        endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 6);
        startDate = ((startDate.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0'
                : '')
                + (startDate.getMonth() + 1)
                + "/"
                + ((startDate.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + startDate
                        .getDate())
                + "/"
                + startDate.getFullYear();

        endDate = ((endDate.getMonth() + 2) < 10 ? '0' : '')
        //this might have some flaws if i make it to 2 it works but this is short term fix and will break again
                + (endDate.getMonth() + 1)
                + "/"
                + ((endDate.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + endDate
                        .getDate())
                + "/"
                + endDate.getFullYear();

        document.getElementById("ok").innerHTML = startDate;
        document.getElementById("napa").innerHTML = endDate;

        $(".next")
                .click(
                        function () {
                            document.getElementById("tabletbody").innerHTML = "";
                            var startdt = new Date($('#ok')
                                    .text());
                            startdt.setDate(startdt
                                    .getDate() + 7);
                            document.getElementById("ok").innerHTML = (getDateFormat(startdt));

                            var enddt = new Date($('#napa')
                                    .text());
                            enddt
                                    .setDate(enddt
                                            .getDate() + 7);
                            document.getElementById("napa").innerHTML = (getDateFormat(enddt));
                            updateCompass();

                            return false;

                        });

        function getDateFormat(d) {
            var month = ((d.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '')
                    + (d.getMonth() + 1);
            var dd = (d.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '')
                    + d.getDate();
            return month + "/" + dd + "/" + d.getFullYear();

        }

        $(".previous").click(function () {
            document.getElementById("tabletbody").innerHTML = "";
            var startdt = new Date($('#ok').text());
            startdt.setDate(startdt.getDate() - 7);

            $('#ok').text(getDateFormat(startdt));
            var enddt = new Date($('#napa').text());
            enddt.setDate(enddt.getDate() - 7);

            $('#napa').text(getDateFormat(enddt));
            updateCompass();

            return false;
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<div id="ok"></div>
<div id="napa"></div>
```

Comment: I had a code that worked till July 31st, do you think adding if condition will solve any date issues forever(leap year , 5 weeks month......)?

Comment: let me check it

Comment: thx please let me know if this code will be perfect on the long run!

Comment: I have updated the code and test with leap year 2020-02-29

Comment: thx a lot @vindhyachal working good, I hope this code will not break.